# "Чтобы" — слитно и "что бы" — раздельно. Как определить?

Tags: орфография

Возможно ли заменить **чтобы** и **что бы** какими-то схожими словами, *чтобы* узнать: где пишется слитно, а где —- раздельно?

Answer (score 7):

Если частицу ***бы*** можно без изменения смысла разделить со словом "что", то пишется раздельно.
***Что бы*** такого сделать? - **Что** сделать **бы** такого?

Если вставить после "что" другое слово без изменения смысла невозможно, то пишется вместе.
*Чтобы сделать самокат, нужно три доски и два колеса.*

Как вариант, можно перед ***что()бы*** поставить фразу "для того": если смысл фразы не меняется — значит, слитно.

Comment: Что бы такое  почитать, чтобы было интересно? = Что такое почитать, для того чтобы было интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто: Если «чтобы» отвечает на вопрос «с какой целью», то пишется слитно. Во всех остальных случаях — раздельно.

Comment: Возможно ли заменить чтобы и что бы какими-то схожими словами? Так ведь в вопросе Kraska 54 говорится. Не понятно, чем советуете заменить.